# Prove that $(\{[0],[a],[2a],...,[(b-1)a]\},+)$ is a subgroup of $(\mathbb{Z}_n,+)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> $n$ is not a prime number. Then $n=ab$ for some $a,b\in \mathbb{N}$: $1<a<n$ and $1<b<n$. Prove that $(\{[0],[a],[2a],...,[(b-1)a]\},+)$ is a subgroup of $(\mathbb{Z}_n,+)$.

It seems that I did the proof, but I'm not sure that everything is correct.
My solution:
Suppose $k\in [0,b-1]$. Its is sufficient to show that $$\forall k \exists l,[ka]_n=[l]_n$$ Then $$ka=l+rn$$ for some $r\in \mathbb{Z}$ Just take $r=0$ and $l=ka$. So we are done.

Comment: What does the symbol $[.]$ mean?

Comment: Notations:
$\mathbb{Z}_n=\{[0],[1],...,[n-1]\}$,
$[x]=\{y\in \mathbb{Z}: x\equiv y \bmod{n} \}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say $S=\{[0],[a],[2a],...[(b-1)a]\}$ and $x,y\in S$

We need to show that $x-y\in S$ and by one step subgroup test, we are done.

Since $x,y\in S$, we have $x\equiv ia\pmod{n}$ and $y\equiv ja\pmod{n}$ where $0\le i,j\le b-1$

**Case I:** $i=j$. Then $\,\,x-y$ is trivially in $S$ as $[0]\in S$

**Case II:** $i>j$, then $0\le j<i\le b-1$

Then, $0< i-j\le b-1$ and so $x-y\equiv (i-j)a\pmod{n}$, thus $x-y\in S$

**Case III:** $j>i$, then $0\le i<j\le b-1$

Then, we have $-(b-1)\le i-j<0$

$x-y\equiv (i-j)a\pmod n$

So, we have $x-y\equiv [(i-j)a\, +\, n]\pmod n\equiv [(i-j)+b]a\pmod n$

Now, $1\le b+i-j<b$ and hence, you proved your claim.

Comment: Oh, thanks. I got it. I didn't know about one-step subgroup test. But also I'd like to know, what can be wrong with my proof.

Comment: @Mihail The only ways of showing this are $$(1)\,\, \text{ One Step Subgroup Test}$$ $$(2)\,\, \text{ Two Step Subgroup Test }$$ $$(3)\,\, \text{ Showing that all the four properties of group are satisfied}$$. All would use the same logic as above. In your proof, you showed $ka=l$ which takes you nowhere!